# Change not triggered when jquery function is re-launched

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have a jquery function which checks if a checkbox is checked, and then shows or hides divs accordingly.
I also have another function which add a new part of the form with some divs with class "disabled-price" in it, so when a new part is added, I relaunch my function.

But from there, the "change" event is not triggered anymore... The first part works but not the second one.

```
function disableInfo() {

    //first part
    var $disabledInfo = $('#invalidityInfo');
    if($disabledInfo.is(':checked')) {
        $('.disabled-price').show();
    } else {
        $('.disabled-price').hide();
    }

    //second part
    $disabledInfo.unbind('change');
    $disabledInfo.change(function() {
        if($disabledInfo.is(':checked')) {
            $('.disabled-price').show();
        } else {
            $('.disabled-price').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Why do you need to `unbind()`/`bind()` the event again? The element hasn't changed, so the event should still be available.

Comment: Actually I added this line because it was not working anyway... So with or without, the change event is not triggered the second time

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same `id` in your page? Are the elements added to the DOM dynamically?

Comment: I do not have multiple elements with the same id. And some elements are added dynamically, some divs with class "disabled-price"

Answer (score 0):

In order to capture events on dynamic elements you can use :

[.delegate( selector, eventType, handler )](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

or

[.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Here is an example :

```
// wait for the document to be ready.
$(function(){  // equivalent to $(document).ready(function(){

    var $disabledInfo = $('#invalidityInfo');

    // initial check 
    if($disabledInfo.is(':checked')) {
        $('.disabled-price').show();
    } else {
        $('.disabled-price').hide();
    } 

    // create event listener 
    // use .on or .delegate to catch dynamic elements that are added on the fly

    $('body').delegate('change','#invalidityInfo',function(){
        if($this.is(':checked')) {
            $('.disabled-price').show();
        } else {
            $('.disabled-price').hide();
        } 
    });


})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, i do not need to initialize it just once since I am trying to relaunch the function when I add some new divs (with class "disabled-price") on my page

Comment: you are adding divs with class "disabled-price" dynamically ?

Comment: @symdev in this case try to replace only ``$disabledInfo.change(`` with 
``$disabledInfo.on('change',`` and it should work

Comment: @symdev try `.delegate`

Comment: not working but i just realized that when I disable my icheck jquery plugin, it is working... so i will search this way. Thanks anyway